# Why does "Infragistics" folder generate a "missing assembly" compile time error?

Tags: c#, wpf, infragistics, xamgrid

Dear community member.

While I have programmed in C# for a number of years, I must admit that I am new to WPF and Infragistics controls.  Recently I came across an unexpected compile time error and I was wondering what might be causing it:

*The type or namespace name 'Controls' does not exist in the namespace 'Sandbox.WpfApp'   (are you missing an assembly reference?)*

Thoughts?

**STEPS TO REPRODUCE**

1. Create a WPF project
2. Add a `XamGrid` to MainWindow.xaml
3. This step is important: name the `XamGrid`

   - `<ig:XamGrid x:Name="abc">`
4. Compile and run the application... everything is ok!
5. Create an *Infragistics* folder within the project
6. Add a WPF user control to the *Infragistics* folder
7. Compile the application: the before mentioned error is generated

What is interesting is:

- if you remove `x:Name="abc"` from the `XamGrid` => no compile-time error
- if at step #5 you had named the folder "IntragisticsTest" => no compile-time error

**ADDITIONAL CONTEXT***

- Infragistics WPF4 controls (version: 12.2.20122.1000)
- Visual Studio 2013

Comment: This is a namespace conflict that occurs when you don't use `global::`.  What line of source generates the error?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/03/11/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-two.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the feedback SLaks, much appreciated!  The compile-time error points to the `ig:XamGrid` definition in the XAML.

Comment: @SLaks: I have never seen naming conflicts expressed quite this way before, but perhaps you are right.  If I follow the the *STEPS TO REPRODUCE* and create a class named *Infragistics* (instead of the folder)... I see the same result => *The type or namespace name 'Controls' does not exist in the namespace*

Comment: Assuming it is a namespace conflict, do you know why the error goes away when I remove the x:Name="abc" property from the `XamGrid`?

Comment: Because then you never end up using their `Infragistics` namespace in C# source.